# Using a TinyMCE textarea and posting form using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, textarea

I m using tinyMCE for textareas and posting my form through AJAX.
But when I m trying to save textarea value, the value in the text area is not being recorded.

My text area `<textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="input"></textarea>`

and my ajax code

```
var formData = {
        'flashcard_title'           : $('input[name=flashcard_title]').val(),
        'flashcard_id'              : $('input[name=flashcard_id]').val(),
        'content'                   : $('textarea[name=content]').val(),

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', 
        url         : 'slides',
        data        : formData, 
        dataType    : 'json', 
        encode      : true
    })
```

Please help. Thanks guys

Comment: Would you provide more details on the issue you are facing? What is the response from server? Also do you have the csrf token added to the post form?

Answer (score 0):

This seems broken:

```
var formData = {
    'flashcard_title'       : $('input[name=flashcard_title]').val(),
    'flashcard_id'          : $('input[name=flashcard_id]').val(),
    'content'               : $('textarea[name=content]').val(),
```

Try deleting that final `,` and adding the missing brace `}` at the end.